# Redirect from www to non-www not working in Nginx

Tags: nginx, https, redirect, 301-redirect

I'm having trouble redirecting from www to non-www for one of my domain names. In the past I have used a similar (read identical) configuration and it just worked. Somehow this doesn't work however.

The first section I have is for my desired configuration at https://example.org. Basically no www and served over SSL.

```
server {
    server_name example.org;

    root /var/www/example.org/html;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    access_log /var/www/example.org/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example.org/logs/error.log;

    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;

    # pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
    # concurs with nginx's one
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 
}
```

Then I have a section to redirect www on https to non-www on https:

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.org) {
        return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 443 ssl; 
    server_name www.example.org;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.org/privkey.pem; 
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; 

}
```

Then I have a section to redirect http to https:

```
server {
    if ($host = example.org) {
        return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80;
    server_name example.org;
    return 404; 
}
```

Finally I have a redirect for www http to non-www https.

```
server {
    if ($host = www.example.org) {
        return 301 https://example.org$request_uri;
    } 

    listen 80;
    server_name www.example.org;
    return 404; 
}
```

What I expect to see is this:

- https non-www -> show the site;
- https www -> redirect to https non-www;
- http non-www -> redirect to https non-www;
- http www -> redirect to https non-www.

What actually happens:

- https non-www -> shows the site (good).
- https www -> shows the default NIGNX page (bad).
- http non-www -> redirects to https non-www and then shows the site (good).
- http www -> redirects to https www and then shows the default NGINX page (bad).

What am I missing here? It would seem to me that this should work, but it doesn't. I have reloaded/restarted nginx, made sure the file was actually loaded, reorganized the order of some of these sections, but it hasn't helped.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: Why do you `if ($host` everything? You've already established the host trough the `server_name`? Also, what does `nginx - t` say?

Comment: @Ginnungagap Thank you for your tip. `nginx -t` showed that there was a conflict. Which made no sense, but it led me to grep the folder and find out that certbot injected the same directives inside of the default nginx config file. So my adjustments were being ignored. I also got rid of the `if ($host` injected by certbot and simplified the file by consolidating it to three, instead of four sections. It's now better and it works. Thank you.

Comment: thrn feel free to answer your own question

Comment: @Ginnungagap Is it possible for you to post your `nginx` config? I would like to setup my site in exactly the same way. Did you have to set both `CNAME` for both `@` and `www`. Or did you have to make any changes except pointing `CNAME` to` @` only.